# How long can „perpetual“ flasks run?

Tags: thermodynamics

I keep encountering hoax „perpetual“ flasks like [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Rbg10U3aTrM), which is uncovered in the video. 
[image]

They would (as they aren’t frictionless) violate the first law of thermodynamics and thus cannot be perpetual. But the frictions preventing them from being so (formation of droplet at the output and possibly internal friction of the fluid?) seem tiny to me as well.

If I introduce potential energy into the system, by emptying the bottle with which I fill it from an height h relative to the output, can someone estimate, how long it could run, before succumbing to frictions?

Obviously, it would depend on the fluid. Let’s say water.

Although, I am thinking, it is of no use if I drop a small quantity of water into the empty apparatus from large height. Is it only the amount of water later on its way  between input and output, with which I could really add potential energy?

Comment: there   is also this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCKC-QVcVn0